# How do I change the position of HTML inserted during a Wordpress Action

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to PHP development. I'm trying to build a WordPress plugin for experience.

I'm using:

```
function spg_insert_comment_form() {

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    print 'Test Form Position';
}

}

add_action( 'comment_form', 'spg_insert_comment_form' );
```

To insert additional html into the contact form. Eventually, I will add a form that submits with the comment.

The problem is (or at least the only one I see) is that it's inserting my html after the submit button. Is there a hook that would allow me to place my code before the submit button or should I take another approach such as kicking off JavaScript that inserts my form.

**Edit:** While waiting for a reply I was able to successfully solve the problem using PHP to call a JavaScript function. It works great but I'm trying to learn development best practices as well. Is this approach considered hackish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out all possible actions for comment_form, like:

- comment_form_before
- comment_form_top
- comment_form
- comment_form_after

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form#Related

Comment: I found "comment_form_after_fields" which would be perfect for what I'm trying to do but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you are looking for is the `priority` variable..

[see API Docs here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

```
<?php
   add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
?>
```

quoted:

"Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action."

maybe giving it a higher value will put it farther on the bottom? But it depends on what other plugins are hooked on to the comment form though

Comment: I tried this. It had no visible effect. It appears to operate on the order functions are run. If comments are handled all in one function it's possible priority wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

Came here searching for solution, add action 'comment_form_after_fields' with arguments added the field before comment text area. Hope will help anybody who'll come searching in future :)